# IIS server disables asp element but works on local

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iis, web

My login page works fine on local when run via VS with IIS express, but when put on our server 2012 with IIS 8 it disables the login button.

Original code:
    `<asp:Button ID="cmdCont" Visible="true"  runat="server" Text="Continue" CssClass="btn btn-success"/>`

Local Rendered:
`<input type="submit" name="cmdCont" value="Continue" id="cmdCont" class="btn btn-success">`

Server/IIS8 Rendered:
`<input name="cmdCont" value="Continue" id="cmdCont" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled btn btn-success" type="submit">`

The btn/btn-success is a standard bootstrap class, and you can see the button with the green colour when accessed from the server, just can't click it.

Can anyone please help or assist me, the button needs to work/be clickable.

Comment: What is adding `disabled="disabled"`? It is impossible for us to answer it. Something is setting the attribute and adding that class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.disabledcssclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Nothing that I can think of or have in my project would do that.
But why would it only do it on the server and not on local ?

Comment: Part of the .NET framework...

Comment: Okay, but how do I get rid of it ?